# Is there a way to detect if two texts are relating to the same brand?

Tags: python, string-comparison

Given two texts, for example: "Cocacola" and "Coca-cola", is there a way that is generalizable for other brands and other texts to detect if the two texts are relating to the same brand?

Right now I have this simple code:

```py
def matches_company_name(name1: str, name2: str):
    name1_lower_case = name1.lower()
    name2_lower_case = name2.lower()
    return (
        name1_lower_case in name2_lower_case
        or name2_lower_case in name1_lower_case
    )
```

I have a couple ideas to add to the possible tests:

- Make a POS tagging and compare ORGs
- Make separation by spaces or dashes and check if are parts in common. (Maybe to general)
- Making some kind of edit distance threshold (Maybe will fail for strings that differ a lot in the length)

Is there already a way to achieve this? Do you have any good ideas (heuristics) to add to the tests?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't well suited to open-ended questions ("what algorithm best implements goal X?") -- our format works best for questions that are narrow and amenable to canonically-correct answers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy where should be the best forum to post this kind of question?. Let me reformulate the question, I just want an algorithm that does the job. I don't care that much if it is the best

Comment: You could take a look at the [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance, implemented in this [module](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/). This is a measure of similarity between strings. The wikipedia also mentions other methods.

Comment: If you put them in the same case and remove all punctuation, is that good enough? (Probably impossible to detect that Coke and Coca-cola are the same without just *knowing* it.)

Comment: You can index by sound, rather than text: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `fuzzywuzzy` package, specially `partial_token_set_ratio` which gave very good results.

### Usage example:

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


MIN_SCORE = 0.7
s1 = "cocacola"
s2 = "coca-cola"

is_same_company = fuzz.partial_token_set_ratio(s1, s2) > MIN_SCORE
print(is_same_company)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement what you mention above ,but as a simple solution you can use **re** lib in python like this :

```
import re
pattern = r'cocacola'
text = 'Coca-colafd   '

tt=text.lower()
s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s\d]','',tt)
# s = re.sub("\d+", " ", tt)
if re.match(pattern, s):
    print("Match and the word is -->>"+  str(s))
else:
    print("No match")
```

and the output will be like this

> Match and the word is -->>cocacolafd

and as you can see it match even when you add extra character to word

notice that you can specify the output by remove digit and whitespace and repeaters by the lib it self and make it more reliable

and for further infos you can see the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

for instance: here is a pattern for delete digits:

```
s = re.sub("\d+", " ", tt)
```

Comment: I know regular expressions but this approach it's to manual. I will have to create lots of rules.

Comment: then as you said above you need to make "bag of word" and "tf-idf" to implement  word2vec approach to make this happen, best regards @Ángel